# VBA to copy and paste Range Values is too slow

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I'm using this code and it works just fine but it runs very slow.
Does someone has a different approach for this?

```
Sub CopyPaste()

 Dim sourcerange As Workbook
 Dim currentrange As Workbook

 Dim r As Integer
 Dim c As Integer
 Dim z As Integer
 
 
 Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Data Gantt")
 Set sourceworkbook = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EVC Project Data")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

r = 2
c = 16
z = 5

sourceworkbook.Range("C" & r & ":C" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("B" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("A" & r & ":A" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("C" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("E" & r & ":E" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("D" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("G" & r & ":G" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("E" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("F" & r & ":F" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("F" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("J" & r & ":J" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("G" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("L" & r & ":L" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("H" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("P" & r & ":P" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("I" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

r = r + 16
c = c + 16
z = z + 16

sourceworkbook.Range("C" & r & ":C" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("B" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("A" & r & ":A" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("C" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("E" & r & ":E" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("D" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("G" & r & ":G" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("E" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("F" & r & ":F" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("F" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("J" & r & ":J" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("G" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("L" & r & ":L" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("H" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("P" & r & ":P" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("I" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
r = r + 16
c = c + 16
z = z + 16

sourceworkbook.Range("C" & r & ":C" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("B" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("A" & r & ":A" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("C" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("E" & r & ":E" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("D" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("G" & r & ":G" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("E" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("F" & r & ":F" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("F" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("J" & r & ":J" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("G" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("L" & r & ":L" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("H" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sourceworkbook.Range("P" & r & ":P" & c).Copy
currentworkbook.Range("I" & z).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

*****Repeat the same process for another 12 times****

Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is really hard to see what ranges you are copying, and there may be some optimization possible if you can copy a whole range in one go rather than lots of small ranges.

Something you definitely can do is stop excel from calculating the entire worksheet after each modification.

To do this, place the following code at the start of your macro:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

And place the following code at the end of your macro:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```